# WCF Service + Entity Framework: How to send an entity?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, entity-framework-4

some of my methods in the WCF Service returns an entities from the Entity Framework. I cannot add the Web Service reference in my Windows Phone 7 application because of that warning:

> Custom tool warning: Cannot import
>   wsdl:portType Detail: An exception was
>   thrown while running a WSDL import
>   extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet'
>   from assembly
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IBarnGameServiceNEW'] D:\MGameWindowsPhone7\Service
>   References\ServiceReference3\Reference.svcmap

What's the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio not under Administrator account. This helps me.